# tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay: global step = 0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, learning-rate

To find out how to implement both a ANN with exponential decay as well as a with a constant learning rate I looked it up here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/exponential_decay

I have some questions:

```
...
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
starter_learning_rate = 0.1
learning_rate = tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(starter_learning_rate,
global_step,
                                           100000, 0.96, staircase=True)
# Passing global_step to minimize() will increment it at each step.
learning_step = (
    tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    .minimize(...my loss..., global_step=global_step)
)
```

When the global_step is set equal to a variable with the value 0 doesn't that mean that we will have no decay, since

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
                        decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

Therefore if `global_step= 0` follows `decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate`, is this right or am I making a mistake here?

Furthermore, I am a bit confused as to what exactly the 100,000 steps refer to. What exactly is one step? Is it every time an input has been fully fed through the network and backpropagated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example clears your doubt.

```
epochs = 10
global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, dtype= tf.int32)
starter_learning_rate = 1.0

for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("Starting Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch+1,epochs))
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
            
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        
        learning_rate = tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay(
                    starter_learning_rate,
                    global_step,
                    100000, 
                    0.96
        )
        
        
        optimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
        print("Global Step: {}  Learning Rate: {}  Examples Processed: {}".format(global_step.numpy(), learning_rate(), (step + 1) * 100))
        global_step.assign_add(1)
```

Output:

```
Starting Epoch 1/10
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 100
Global Step: 1  Learning Rate: 0.9999996423721313  Examples Processed: 200
Global Step: 2  Learning Rate: 0.9999992251396179  Examples Processed: 300
Global Step: 3  Learning Rate: 0.9999988079071045  Examples Processed: 400
Global Step: 4  Learning Rate: 0.9999983906745911  Examples Processed: 500
Global Step: 5  Learning Rate: 0.9999979734420776  Examples Processed: 600
Global Step: 6  Learning Rate: 0.9999975562095642  Examples Processed: 700
Global Step: 7  Learning Rate: 0.9999971389770508  Examples Processed: 800
Global Step: 8  Learning Rate: 0.9999967217445374  Examples Processed: 900
Global Step: 9  Learning Rate: 0.9999963045120239  Examples Processed: 1000
Global Step: 10  Learning Rate: 0.9999958872795105  Examples Processed: 1100
Global Step: 11  Learning Rate: 0.9999954700469971  Examples Processed: 1200
Starting Epoch 2/10
Global Step: 12  Learning Rate: 0.9999950528144836  Examples Processed: 100
Global Step: 13  Learning Rate: 0.9999946355819702  Examples Processed: 200
Global Step: 14  Learning Rate: 0.9999942183494568  Examples Processed: 300
Global Step: 15  Learning Rate: 0.9999938607215881  Examples Processed: 400
Global Step: 16  Learning Rate: 0.9999934434890747  Examples Processed: 500
Global Step: 17  Learning Rate: 0.999993085861206  Examples Processed: 600
Global Step: 18  Learning Rate: 0.9999926686286926  Examples Processed: 700
Global Step: 19  Learning Rate: 0.9999922513961792  Examples Processed: 800
Global Step: 20  Learning Rate: 0.9999918341636658  Examples Processed: 900
Global Step: 21  Learning Rate: 0.9999914169311523  Examples Processed: 1000
Global Step: 22  Learning Rate: 0.9999909996986389  Examples Processed: 1100
Global Step: 23  Learning Rate: 0.9999905824661255  Examples Processed: 1200
```

Now if you keep your Global step as 0. ie Remove the increment operation from above code.
Output:

Starting Epoch 1/10

```
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 100
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 200
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 300
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 400
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 500
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 600
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 700
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 800
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 900
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 1000
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 1100
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 1200
Starting Epoch 2/10
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 100
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 200
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 300
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 400
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 500
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 600
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 700
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 800
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 900
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 1000
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 1100
Global Step: 0  Learning Rate: 1.0  Examples Processed: 1200
```

Suggestion - Instead of using **tf.compat.v1.train.exponential_decay** use **tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay**.
This is how the simplest example would look like.

```
def create_model1():
    initial_learning_rate = 0.01
    lr_schedule = tf.keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate,
        decay_steps=100000,
        decay_rate=0.96,
        staircase=True)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(5,)))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 6, 
                                    activation='relu', 
                                    name = 'd1'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='softmax', name = 'O2'))
    
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model


model = create_model1()
model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 100, epochs = 100)
```

You can also use Callback like tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler to implement your decay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So one train step is equivalent to one epoch?
You refer to train- and decay steps what is the difference? 
If I run a program with 1,200 rows of input, for 2,000 epochs.
WIll there be a decay step in the training or not? 
And to make things clear: if ```global_steps = 0``` -> no decay, right?

Comment: Can you plz accept and upvote if the solution worked.